# I want to add dot between number

Tags: linux

i'm going to convert Epoch time to '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N'
but "converted Epoch time(date -> Epoch time)" is expressed nanoseconds.
if convert "1612483249166", output "53067-07-24 10:26:46.000".

so i want to input "1612483249.166"
how ??????

```
ptime1=`echo $(($evtime2+$p))` ###Epoch time
ptime2=`gdate -u -d "1970-01-01 $ptime1 seconds" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N'`
```

_i'm sorry if the sentence if awkward. thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about using the calculated variable `ptime1_`?

```
ptime1=`echo $(($evtime2+$p))` ###Epoch time
ptime1_=`expr $ptime1 / 1000`
ptime2=`gdate -u -d "1970-01-01 $ptime1_ seconds" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N'`
```